# Загрузить SQLite в ОЗУ

Tags: sqlite3, sqlite, производительность

Заметил, что если создать таблицу в SQLite без присоединения физического файла, то все операции выполняются значительно быстрее. После выполнения скрипта остается только выполнить .backup filename.db, чтобы сохранить результаты работы. Если же приаттачить пустую БД с созданными таблицами  - те же операции выполняются в десятки раз медленнее. Есть ли возможность загружать и работать с БД в ОЗУ?

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая [возможность](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html). Нужно открыть базу, используя специальное имя файла :memory:, тогда база данных создается целиком в памяти.

```
c = sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);
```

База данных существует до тех пор, пока открыто соединение. Ну и, кроме того, всегда можно создать диск в памяти и открыть файл на этом диске.

Comment: Хотел бы добавить, что возможно это не только с SQLite, но пользоватся этим целесообразно восновном только для временных таблиц.

Comment: Судя по ссылке, речь идет о создании новой БД. Мне же хотелось бы загрузить в память уже сущестующую. Я смотрел документацию по SQLite(правда в английском не силен) и простого способа загрузить всю БД в память не нашел. Может есть какой-то хитрый путь или способ загрузить отдельные таблицы в ОЗУ? Буду благодарен за любые способы увеличения производительности SQLite.

Comment: Можно сначала открыть `:memory:`, потом сделать `attach database database_file as f;`. Потом все необходимые таблицы скопировать: `create table t1 as select * from f.t1;`. После построить все необходимые для работы индексы. Потом, собственно говоря, работа, потом транзакция по возвращению данных обратно в основную базу.